# What are the file update requirements of HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Under the Simple Coherency Model section of [the HDFS Archiectiure guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html), it states (emphasis mine):

> HDFS applications need a write-once-read-many access model for files. A file once created, written, and closed **need not** be changed. This assumption simplifies data coherency issues and enables high throughput data access. A Map/Reduce application or a web crawler application fits perfectly with this model. There is a plan to support appending-writes to files in the future.

I am confused by the use of "need not" here. Do they really mean "must not" or "should not"? If so, how can programs like HBase provide update support? If they really do mean "need not" (i.e. ["doesn't have to"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/need_not)), what is trying to be conveyed? What file systems requires you to change a file once written?

Answer (score 1):

Up to what I know, the `need not` is part of the **assumption** that "simplifies data coherency issues that enables high...". Actually means `can't`. But you can delete and create again the hole file.

After hadoop 0.20.2-append (like shown [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-R4uUpa94Q4Y/Txb4A5iFrUI/AAAAAAAAABo/_gNc7YOHGvw/s1600/hadoop-vers.png)) you can append data.

For all I read, I understand that HBase uses mainly memory ([WAL? section 11.8.3](http://hbase.apache.org/book/perf.writing.html)) and modifications gets appended as marks. For example, to delete a column it makes a *tombstone* (see [section 5.8.1.5](http://hbase.apache.org/book/versions.html)) just marking the delete, and periodical compactation.

Maybe I am wrong. Good moment for me to learn the exact explanation :)